# How to use the TObservable<T>.RemoveListener() in Delphi Spring Framework?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

In the Delphi Spring framework there is an example on how to use TObservable.AddListener() in the \Spring4D\Samples\SpringDemos\Demo.Patterns\Observer folder.

But there is not an example showing how to use TObservable.RemoveListener().

Here I add a listener

    `FEditorMonitor := TEditorMonitor.Create;
    FEditorMonitor.AddListener(TCurrentTimeEditUpdater.Create(Edit1));`

if I try to use the following code to remome Edit1 from the Listeners, Edit1 continues to be notified:

`FEditorMonitor.RemoveListener(TCurrentTimeEditUpdater.Create(Edit1));`

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should REMOVE the PREVIOUSLY ADDED listener, not create YET ANOTHER NEW listener.

```
var x: TCurrentTimeEditUpdater;
x := TCurrentTimeEditUpdater.Create(Edit1);

FEditorMonitor.AddListener(x); 

...

FEditorMonitor.RemoveListener(x);
x.Free;
{ optionally } x := nil;
```

Perhaps your confusion is shown in your idea that you were going "to remome Edit1 from the Listeners". But `Edit1` was never and never could be a listener. It just does not have the proper behaviour.
What you can add to or remove from listeners collection - is a separate bridging object of some `T....Updater` class. Not the `Edit1` itself.

[Listeners Collections containing(..., Updater1, ...) ] -> [Updater1 for(Edit1)] -> [Edit1]

Your starting code looks to me like

```
Procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(...);
var NewForm: TMainForm;
begin
    NewForm := TMainForm.Create;
    NewForm.Close;
end;
```

This would not close the form you already see on the display, more so - it would just leak the memory.

Comment: I've also addes a check *before* adding a listener again: if not Assigned(x) then x := TCurrentTimeEditUpdater.Create(Edit1); FEditorMonitor.AddListener(x);

Comment: perhaps there can be search in the listeners collections, or whatever, that is up to you.